# Write permissions inside shell script

Tags: shell-script

How to check user has write permission to the directory,the directory name is passed as a command line argument.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103806/bash-test-if-a-directory-is-writable-by-a-given-uid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @SHW is not a good idea and it is returning incorrect results in some cases.

Please just use the `test` command (or it's `[`alias):

```
if [ -w "$dirname" ]; then
    echo "$dirname is writable"
fi
```

as the `test` command with its `-w` test will not check the historical `UNIX permission bits` but rather call `access(2)` to verify writability.

The advantage of using `access(2)` is that `access` also includes `ACL` influences that are missing if you just check the traditional UNIX permission bits.

Answer (score -1):

Simple script to find out the write permission

```
ls -ld directory | cut -c -10 > temp_perm
owner_perm=`cut -c 3 temp_perm`
group_perm=`cut -c 6 temp_perm`
other_perm=`cut -c 9 temp_perm`
[ "$owner_perm" -eq "w" ] && echo "Owner have write permission"
[ "$group_perm" -eq "w" ] && echo "Group have write permission"
[ "$other_perm" -eq "w" ] && echo "Other have write permission"
```

Comment: -1 way too complicated, without being useful enough. A simple `[ -w directory ]` is enough.

Comment: I know that. Since, OP is new to the forum. I thought to explain it in a simple way. Your solution is more straight forward.